# Wicket Kendo DataTable filter issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, wicket

Are there any examples out there on how to property implement a filter using an IColumn under Wicket-Kendo DataTable component?

Note please..  I am using Wicket as the framework so I'd like to do this vi my framework..

I have the following:

```
 columns.add(new PropertyColumn("Type", "publicationType") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public String getFilterable() {
                            return "{multi: true, dataSource: [{" +
                                "City: 'Seattle'," +
                              "},{" +
                               "City: 'Tacoma'," +
                              "},{" +
                                "City: 'Kirkland'," +
                              "},{" +
                                "City: 'Redmond'," +
                              "},{" +
                                "City: 'London'" +
                              "}]," +
                              "checkAll: false" +
                            "}}";
        }
```

I have a datasource that I will use to add the actual options I need, but this does not render a checkable list for filtering on the column.  Any advise??

Comment: If you don't get response here then please ask in Wicket-JQuery-UI forum (Google groups). I am not sure that Sebastien Briquet follows SO.

Comment: Almost immediate response with good info.  Thank you so much!!!!